# Kubernetes mount volume keeps timeing out even though volume can be mounted from sudo mount

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have a read only persistent volume that I'm trying to mount onto the statefulset, but after making some changes to the program and re-creating the pods, the pod can now no longer mount to the volume.

PV yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: foo-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  nfs:
    server: <ip>
    path: "/var/foo"
  claimRef:
    name: foo-pvc
    namespace: foo
```

PVC yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: foo-pvc
  namespace: foo
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  storageClassName: ""
  volumeName: foo-pv
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

Statefulset yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foo-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http 
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: foo-app
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: foo-statefulset
  namespace: foo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo-app
  serviceName: foo-app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: foo-app
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: foo-service-account
      containers:
      - name: fooContainer
        image: <image>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
        - name: writer-data
          mountPath: <path>
        - name: nfs-objectd
          mountPath: <path>
      volumes:      
      - name: nfs-foo
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: foo-pvc          
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: writer-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
      storageClassName: "foo-sc"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 2Gi
```

k describe pod reports "Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[nfs-foo]: timed out waiting for the condition".   There is a firewall between the machine running kubernetes and the NFS, however the port has been unblocked, and the folder has been exported for mounting on the NFS side.  Running sudo mount -t nfs :/var/foo /var/foo is able to successfully mount the NFS, so I don't understand why kuebernetes isn't about to mount it anymore.   Its been stuck failing mount for several days now.   Is there any other way to debug this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error “unable to attach or mount volumes …….timed out waiting for condition”, there were some similar issues reported to the Product Team and it is a known issue. But, this error is more observed on the preemptible/spot nodes when the node is preempted. In similar occurrences of this issue for other users, upgrading the control plane version resolved this issue temporarily in preemptible/spot nodes.

Also, if you are not using any preemptible/spot nodes in your cluster, this issue might have happened when the old node is replaced by a new node. If you are still facing this issue, try [upgrading the control plane](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster#upgrade_cp) to the same version i.e. you can execute the following command:

```
$ gcloud container clusters upgrade CLUSTER_NAME --master --zone ZONE --cluster-version VERSION
```

Another workaround to fix this issue would be remove the stale VolumeAttachment with the following command:

```
$ kubectl delete volumeattachment [volumeattachment_name]
```

After running the command and thus removing the VolumeAttachment, the pod should eventually pick up and retry. You can read more about this issue and its cause [here](https://veducate.co.uk/kubelet-unable-attach-volumes/).